# Hyperledger on Bluemix: Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm running a simple Hyperledger network on Bluemix.  I can deploy, and invoke, but not query.  The chaincode function, Init sets up a value for var, "abc" ... `stub.PutState("abc", []byte(strconv.Itoa(Aval)))`

I should be able to query "abc" as validation the code is ready to use.  Instead, I'm seeing this error:

> "... Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment
>   transaction for  - LedgerError - ResourceNotFound:
>   ledger: resource not found)"

The query json is:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "query",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID": {
      "name": "my chaincode id"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
      "function": "read",
      "args": [
        "abc"
      ]
    },
    "secureContext": "user_type1_3"
  },
  "id": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is the list of probable causes of the error

> Could not get deployment transaction for - LedgerError -
>   ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found

**1. Chaincode did not get deployed correctly.** To check if the
    chaincode was deployed correctly, you need to check the peer logs to
    see if there were any errors when the deploy transaction was sent.

**2. Chaincode got deployed correctly, but the consensus mechanism hasnt
    yet completed.** You should ideally wait for a few minutes after
    deploying a chaincode before you try to query it.

**3. The Chaincode got deployed, but the chaincode ID/name specified
    while trying to send a query is incorrect.** You need to make sure you
    use the same chaincode ID that comes in the response when you deploy
    a chaincode.

Comment: Thanks - I just deleted the service, recreated it, and redeployed the code.  This time I ensured it deployed.  I wonder if I initiated the problem when I first deployed because I hit the "Try it" button a few times when it wasn't clear from the button that I had clicked it.  Thanks again!

Comment: If you found this answer useful you may upvote it  http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote